# Remove old-release files after upgrade

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, package-management, 15.10, repository

I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 15.10 to 16.04. Since I did not do a fresh install, i suspect that there are some system files/packages/repositories related to 15.10 still present in new release.

One such example is shown in the image below:

[image: older]

Is there any way to remove these old files/packages/repositories and upgrade them to match with the new release?

Answer (score 1):

There should not be any old repos after an upgrade.

The "Cdrom" is not a repo. You can delete it if you want.

Comment: But why is it showing cdrom for 15.10? Shouldn't it be for 16.04?

Comment: It shows that cdrom, because you initially installed Ubuntu from it.

Comment: @RD017 It shows the original installation media only. The upgrade was online.

Comment: @Pilot6 How can I delete Cdrom?

Comment: Easy... Select it and press "Remove".